# Why is connection not established with ec2 public IP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip-address, serversocket

We have built a vehicle tracking system (VTS) device.I have a PHP script which listens to the client connection.

A connection is established when we connect using the Private IP of an EC2 instance, but when we try to put an external IP or public IP in the php script, then it shows an error.

How can I solve this??

I have launched a Linux virtual machine with Amazon EC2. Then connect to the Linux instance from Windows using putty. There is a php script which listens to incoming connections. When I put the Private IP of EC2 then it gets connected, but when I put the public IP it throws the error "unable to bind ip[99]"

```
public function __construct($bind_ip,$port)
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $this->hooks = array();

    $this->config["ip"] = $bind_ip;
    $this->config["port"] = $port;

    $this->master_socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    socket_bind($this->master_socket,$this->config["ip"],$this->config["port"]) or die("Issue Binding");
    socket_getsockname($this->master_socket,$bind_ip,$port);
    socket_listen($this->master_socket);
    SocketServer::debug("Listenting for connections on {$bind_ip}:{$port}");
}
```

We want to get data from the vehicle tracking device. We can set the IP address to that device and put that in the PHP script, but when I run it using the public IP it throws the error "unable to bind ip[99]"

Comment: What you see is by design.  EC2 does not expose the external public IP to the instance's IP stack; instead, the public IP is translated to the private IP by the Internet Gateway, which does static 1:1 NAT automatically and requires no separate configuration.  Binding to the internal address is correct, or to all interfaces (e.g. `0.0.0.0`) and will still allow you to accept connections to the external IP if your VPC network setup is all correct. Please confirm: when you bind to the private IP, can you still connect to the public IP?  You should, and if so, then the setup is correct.

Answer (score 0):

VTS Systems needs static IPs. Are you aure the public one you are putting is static? Public ips are in most cases subnetted.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure EC2 instance security groups are correctly configured.
Try telnet  using ip and port you configured with in the EC2 instance.
for Eg: telnet 192.168.0.10 25 , (25 is the port number).

Comment: Yes, i have tried using telnet. it get connected with private IP but when i telnet using public ip it shows unable to bind external IP